# minimize and getting back the display

Tags: java-me, midp, midlet, lcdui

I want to minimize my app and after the timer end get it back.

I use code below.

To minimize application use following line of code:

```
   Display.getDisplay (MIDLET_CLASS_NAME).setCurrent (null);
```

To get the screen back use the following:

```
   Display.getDisplay (MIDLET_CLASS_NAME).setCurrent (myCanvas);
```

But when phone display is dismissed and going to clock mode my midlet display isn't shown until press any button.

any idea?

Comment: Did you try to add a call to MIDLET_CLASS_NAME.resumeRequest() after the call to setCurrent(myCanvas)?

Comment: not yet but i do it as soon as i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it sounds that you expect `setCurrent` to somehow "force" device to immediately display your screen or maybe return only after screen gets visible.

This is not so, as clearly explained in the API documentation for [Display.setCurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#setCurrent%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable%29):

> Requests that a different `Displayable` object be made visible on the display. The **change will typically not take effect immediately**. It may be delayed so that it occurs between event delivery method calls, although it is not guaranteed to occur before the next event delivery method is called. The `setCurrent` method **returns immediately, without waiting** for the change to take place...
>
> ...if the application is in the background, passing a non-null reference to `setCurrent` may be interpreted by the application management software as a request that the application is requesting to be brought to the foreground... These are only requests, and **there is no requirement that the application management software comply with these requests in a timely fashion if at all**...

---

Consider redesigning your MIDlet to adjust to specified behavior.

If `myCanvas` is an instance of Canvas, one can use [showNotify()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#showNotify%28%29) events.

For a generic `Displayable` screen [isShown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Displayable.html#isShown%28%29) method checks if the it is actually visible on the display.

Sometimes it could even make sense to let user explicitly confirm return from background, like

```
display.setCurrent(new Alert("back to foreground", "dismiss to continue...",
        null, AlertType.INFO), myCanvas);
```